# explode() of pyspark.sql is not working as expected even if only one of the record is not following the schema

Tags: arrays, json, pyspark, explode, expand

I have a json file which I would like to convert (say csv) by expanding one of the fields into columns.
I used explode() for this, but it gives an error even if one of the many records is not having the exact schema.

## Input File:

## {"place": "KA", 
  "id": "200", 
  "swversion": "v.002", 
   "events":[ {"time": "2020-05-23T22:34:32.770Z", "eid": 24, "app": "testing", "state": 0} ]}

{"place": "AP",
"id": "100",
"swversion": "v.001",
"events":**[[]]**}

In the above, i want to expand the fields of the "events" and they should become columns. 
Ideal case, "events" is a Array of Struct Type..

## Expected Output File Columns:

## *place, id, swversion, time, eid, app, state*

For this, i have used explode() available in pyspark.sql, but because my second record in the Input file, does not follow the schema where "events" is an Array of Struct Type, explode() fails here by giving an error.

## The code i have used to explode :

df = spark.read.json("InputFile")

ndf = df.withColumn("event", explode("events")).drop("events")

ndf.select("place", "id", "swversion", "**event.***")

The last line fails because of the second record in my input file..

It should not be too difficult for explode() to handle this i believe.
Can you suggest how to avoid

Cannot expand star types

Comment: This is the exact error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(event)`;"

Answer (score 0):

If I change the "events":[[]] to "events":[{}], explode() works fine since again its an Array of StructType, but since I have no control of the input data, i need to handle this.